SignalR working in browser not in android application
I have an expo react native app that is connecting to a signalr hub:
    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("http://server_where_hub_is_hosted:5000/stockHub")
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build();

If i'm using expo go, or testing the app directly on a browser it works fine, it connects to the signalr hub as intended.
But, if i build the app apk with "eas build -p android --profile preview" and install it on my mobile phone, it can't seem to connect to the signalr hub. Why is that? I can connect to the hub via the url on another devices/networks, but not when using the apk.
I'm not even sure if the problem comes from the client side or server side.
Here is my signalr configuration:
using WorkerService;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;


internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddSignalR();
        builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

        builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
        });


        builder.Services.AddWindowsService(options =>
        {
            options.ServiceName = "ReadQueueService";
        });

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ConnectDatabase>();

        builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000");


        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<StockHub>("/stockHub");
        });

        app.Run();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

I've tried specifying the origin, using the internal phone ip and other ways but to no success.

It should be that the latest android does not support HTTP requests by default.
Way 1. Enable http in debug model.
Find the AndroidManifest.xml file, and enable android:usesCleartextTraffic="true".
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>
    ...
 </application>

Way 2. Using https instead of http.
